# Error Unresponsive_Host when trying to Login after generate APK from Mobilefirst

Tags: java, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

i allready success generate APK from my mobilefirst, but when i open my apps it shows error notification said :

> Error connection
>   CommonService.js 
>   {"status":500,"errorCode"."UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service
>   is currently not available","invocationContext":null}

and when i trying to login using my apps, it shows notification error:

> Error Connection 
>   adapterName:login
>   {"status":500,"errorCode"."UNRESPONSIVE_HOST","errorMsg":"The service
>   is currently not available","invocationContext":null}

help me please

Comment: Is it really unresponsive? Or is the URL correct?

Comment: @VivinK What URL? is there any config to set the URL?

Comment: The wlclient.properties. Check if the host/port details are correct

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the MFP Server is not accessible from the Android Device which you are trying with.

You can verify whether the MFP Server is reachable from your Android Device by accessing MFP Operation Console Server URL from the phone browser.

Comment: yes i allready try it and it's success. I can access the MFP Console from my android device..

Comment: Can you please update the question with which Mobilefirst API you are getting this error ?

Comment: 1) Check what details are in the wlclient.properties
2) What API you use to connect to the server.